# AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'items' - FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to update a single record in the database by using the PUT operation in FastAPI. But for some reason, I keep getting this error. All other operations work fine except this one. The error is only raised for the update query.

```
AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is the relevant code.

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

class Blog(BaseModel):
    title: str
    body: str

@app.put('/blog/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, response_class=Response)
def update(id: int, request: schemas.Blog, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    blog = db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id == id)
    if not blog.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                            detail=f'Blog with id {id} not found')
    blog.update(request)
    db.commit()
```

This is the StackTrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi        
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__        
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 111, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 566, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 201, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 150, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 34, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File ".\blog\main.py", line 66, in update
    blog.update(request)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3190, in update
    upd = upd.values(values)
  File "<string>", line 2, in values
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 96, in _generative
    x = fn(self, *args, **kw)
  File "<string>", line 2, in values
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 125, in check
    return fn(self, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\dev\fast-tuts\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\dml.py", line 701, in values
    for k, v in arg.items()
AttributeError: 'Blog' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This worked for me... the update function wanted to update each part of the object, and so each part must be mentioned.  I'm not certain how Bitfumes managed by calling the request object alone.

```
blog.update({'title': request.title, 'body': request.body})
```

EDITED:
Referring the to the request dictionary works too:

```
blog.update(request.dict())
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also challenged with the same problem. However, I realized after printing the request, that exhibits:

"`title='strinaaaaaag' body='asasa'`"

Therefore to solve this issue, just convert your 'request' to the dictionary type:

`dict(request)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@app.put("/blog/update/{id}")
def updateBlog(id, request:schemas.Blog, db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
   blog= db.query(model.Blog).filter(model.Blog.id == id).first()
   
   if not blog:
             raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail=f'blog with id {id} not found')
   else:
  db.query(model.Blog).filter(model.Blog.id == id).update(request.dict())

db.commit()
db.refresh(blog)
return blog
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been following bitfumes' tutorial. I've tried the answers provided by @karlos above and noticed that it might not be the most ideal way to update the data.

Say, if you only want to update the title and not the body, but when I execute it, the title is indeed updated, but the body was also changed to "string" (by default).

Thus, I figured that this might be a working alternative without using the schema.

```
def updateblog (id:int, title:Optional[str]=None, body:Optional[str]=None, db:Session = Depends(get_db)):

    if title!=None:
            db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id==id).update({'title':title})
    
    if body!=None:
            db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id==id).update({'body':body})

    db.commit()
    
    return f'Blog #{id} has been updated.'
```

This happens to work perfectly fine for me and update the data accordingly (that is, if you only want to update the title, only the title will be updated and the original body is not affected, vice versa) without affecting the original data saved in the db.

If anyone happens to know how to do the same thing but using the schema, please let me know! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the attributes of the blog object and update them one by one. You can follow this example: https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/crud/base.py#L49

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem.
Blog is not a dict, this is a Pydentic Base model.
if we check blog type we get here

```
<class 'blog.schemas.Blog'>
```

this is not a key pair dict,that's why it shows us has no attributes "items".
only dict can hold items and value, so we need to convert Blog schema to
dict.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to create a new **UpdateBlog** class in `schemas.py` files

Q.) Why? Why not use the existing **Blog**?

A.) Because there is no **Optional[type]** filed, so if you try to update only one field out of two fields (from main **Blog** class) then it will throw an error. Which means you will have to update all the fields (whether you want it or not)

Here's an example:

- `schemas.py` file

> ```
> from pydantic import BaseModel
> from typing import Optional
>
> class Blog(BaseModel):
>     title: str
>     body: str
>
> class UpdateBlog(BaseModel):
>     title: Optional[str]
>     body: Optional[str]
> ```

- `main.py` file

```
# Update Blog
@app.put('/blog/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
def update(id, request_body: UpdateBlog, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    blog = db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id == id).first()

    if not blog:
        content={'success': False, 'message': f"Blog with id {id} don't exists"}
        return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, content=content)
    
    # exclude_none=True will only update the field which you want to update
    # If you don't want to update "body" then only pass the "title" and "body" field will stay as it is
    db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.id == id).update(request_body.dict(exclude_none=True))
    db.commit()

    content={'success': True, 'message': f"Blog with id {id} Updated"}
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, content=content)
```